# what is the best way to upgrade mysql (5.5) production DB to 5.6 with minimizing downtime

Tags: upgrade, mysql, database-administration

our existing  Database size  around 200Gb,if we can use  consistent,parallel backups methods.
for testing  i migrated development  Db from 5.5 to  5.6  by  taking  mysqldump with  option --single-transaction,but for  production  i am looking  for way  where  i  can upgrade mysql prod Db to  5.6 with minimal downtime.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on [dba.se]


Answer (score 2):

You can build a new server and install 5.6 in that machine and migrate data while keeping your existing DB up and running.

Once you are ready you can just flip the connection string in your app or change the IP address. This will give you no downtime but will require to setup another machine. It's usually easier when you are using cloud hosting (AWS, Rackspace etc).

Another alternative is you might as well put up a expected downtime page in advance if it's not a mission critical application.

Comment: yes we are using  different server but  the problem is how i can manage ongoing  transaction on production DB,because   while taking  mysqldump and restoring  to  new  server their will  be many  transactions performed on my existing  production server.how i  can sync that updated data with  new 5.6  server.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot upgrade 5.5 to 5.6 so the best way is to start a new 5.6 server machine dump the database from 5.5 and point your app to the new server. For huge data migration you can take a look at jetpants to migrate massive data.